# How to copy selected columns from ADLS table to Azure Sql database using azure data factory

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to copy selected columns from ADLS table to Azure sql database.

[i created a dataset fror source and sink side, then what next step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1tJK.png)

Comment: Can you add what you have tried so far? any errors/blockers? sample input and expected output?

Comment: i created a dataset for source and sink side, source excel table having 9 columns and 40 rows, i want only selected columns data

Comment: Please edit to provide a [mcve]. As written, you haven't shown what you tried, or what issues you're having. Also, please post details to your question as an edit, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mapping section of the Copy activity, Import the schemas across the source and the sink datasets and then delete the column mappings which you do not need and only keep the columns that you need to copy over

Comment: This would likely be better as a comment. As currently written, the OP has not shown any effort, other than showing a data set.